# How does Tomura Shigaraki's power not disintegrate his shoes?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In one chapter of the manga it's shown Tomura Shigaraki can disintegrate things with his feet. The disintegration activates apparently in the same way as the hands, when the 5 toes are in contact with the object. How does Tomura Shigaraki's power not disintegrate his shoes then?

Answer (score 2):

This is purely speculation, but socks with holes in them.

Shigaraki's power only triggers if he touches the target with all five fingers/toes on one hand/foot.

So he could have special socks with holes for one or more toes.  Some toes touch the shoe, the others the sock, so neither decays.

Answer (score 0):

The best guess would be socks with one hole for a toe. I am currently on that chapter so idk. I thought up until now that Tenko Shimura's (Tomura Shigaraki but we already knew this if we were this far) quirk could only be used through his hands. So this is a new development to me and pretty much all of us. Maybe the socks got damaged (If he wears special socks) during the whole fighting stuff or maybe when he disintegrated the building.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! I'm not sure what this adds that isn't already in Xavon's answer from last year.

Answer (score -1):

Tomura's power only triggers if he touches the target with all fingers on one hand. So there is no case in which he have holes in his socks or his shoes. His quirk only flows thru his hands.

Comment: The question clearly states that his Quirk also flows through his feet.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I didn't saw he said in manga. So to trigger his power all fingers/toes of one hand/ toe should be in contact only then his quirk works. So it is a possibility that all the fingers of his toe are not touching the same object or might be put his fingers up -down way